# Can I use Excel CELL output in function calls

Tags: excel

I have 2 columns (A & B) of non unique Names and Values, sorted alphabetically by Names. From this I make a column of unique names (J).

For each unique name I get their first and last cells in column A using

Start Cell: CELL("row", INDEX($A:$A,MATCH($J2,$A:$A,0)))

End Cell: CELL("row", INDEX($A:$A,MATCH($J2,$A:$A,1)))

So I end up with columns J, K and L:

J       K   L

Name1   1   10

Name2   11   27

So I now know

- Values data is in column B
- the start row is 1 and end row is 10
- I want to get the minimum for B1:B10

I can concatenate the string "=MIN(B1:B10)" but how can I execute it in a cell?

Comment: you mean use only formulas or, allow vba or other programming?

Comment: @Lei Yang Ideally not VBA but if it has to, then so be it. Intending on supplying this to others who are not programmers and not savvy with macros.

Comment: Why do you need to get the first and last rows for each name? If you require the minimum for each name, why not just use a function such as `MINIFS`? Or, if you're on an old version of Excel, a `MIN(IF(...` array formula?

Comment: @Jos Woolley When this works, I intend on using more stat functions like Average, Count, StdDev, etc). Something I can throw at any function.

Comment: All of those either have an 'IFS' version, or else can be constructed using a conditional IF statement over the Name field. Your current set-up is imaginative yet a touch convoluted. What's more, `CELL` is a volatile function and should be avoided if possible.

Comment: @ Jos Woolley That is good enough advice and gets rid of the middle man work. My failed attempt at over engineering. I did not realise I could apply the IF within so many functions.